# Using Python's pillow/PIL library:

Tags: python

In the following code I am trying to do the following by using Python's pillow/PIL library:

1. Read in an image file, store it as a matrix
2. Access the red, blue, green channel which is an unsigned integer unit8 and convert each channel to float64

**This is my first time using Python's pillow/PIL library and I just wanted to clarify if I have achieved these 2 things correctly.**

Here my is my code I have produced:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('house.jpg')
image = np.array(img)
arr[20,30]
red = np.float64(image[:,:, 0])
green = np.float64(image[:,:,1])
blue = np.float64(image[:,:,2])
```

and for instance, when I use

```
print(red)
```

I get the following output:

```
[[ 34.  41.  49. ...  22.  22.  22.]
 [ 28.  34.  41. ...  23.  23.  23.]
 [ 23.  26.  30. ...  24.  24.  24.]
 ...
 [ 32.  45.  57. ... 105.  97. 109.]
 [ 34.  32.  41. ... 100.  94. 113.]
 [ 33.  36.  52. ...  99.  90. 113.]]
```

Comment: Yes you have, this is what it should look like.

Comment: @RockyLi awesome thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, more simply, use:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('house.jpg')
image=np.array(img,dtype=np.float64)   
...
...
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! does mine give the correct output?

Comment: Yes, it should. Be careful though with `PNG` and `GIF` images, as they may be palettised, so you would be better using `img = Image.open('someImage').convert('RGB')` if you want to be sure of getting RGB values. It doesn't matter with `JPEG` but it does with other formats.